# How can I re-use existing JPA domain objects with JHipster?

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, jhipster

I have a Spring 4.1.0 back-end application with domain classes annotated in JPA (w/Hibernate 4.3.5 as the persistence provider) using Maven as the build tool. I now want to add a web front-end to this app and am playing with JHipster. I want to re-use my existing JPA annotated domain classes and Spring Data JPA repos with JHipster and but have JHipster create controllers and views for each domain model. My first milestone goal is to get basic CRUD functionality on the old domain models from this web app.

Here's an example of what my domain classes look like (the City class):

```
package com.my-company.my-spring-app.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * City generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "city",
     schema = "public",
     uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "name"))
public class City implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 4674557242772722625L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "city_gen",
                   schema = "public",
                   sequenceName = "city_id_seq")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator = "city_gen")
@Column(name = "id",
        unique = true,
        nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "countryid",
            nullable = false)
// @JoinColumn(name = "country_id", nullable = false)
private Country country;

@Column(name = "name",
        unique = true,
        length = 200)
private String name;
...
}
```

Is it possible to re-use this class and the other 50+ that I have already written? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately, it's not possible to reuse them. In jhipster, the views are generated when you generate the entities. The solution would be recreating them using jhipster:entity or [jhipster-uml](http://jhipster.github.io/jhipster_uml.html).

I believe the best you could do might be recreate the entities, preferably commit this version using some SCM and then fine-tuning them using your JPA mapping. Not perfect, but reusing existing entities is currently a jhipster limitation.

Comment: Thanks for the honest answer. I really like JHipster but perhaps it is not the right choice for this project at the moment.

Comment: @jodevan the above discussion seems to answer my question but still confirming again as its been more than a year. You mean to say that its not possible to import an existing database, alongwith data, to jHipster?

Comment: I'm positive this behavior hasn't changed. Creating entities in JHipster does a lot of stuff. From the back-end perspective, it creates POJO's, DAO's, services, changelogs in Liquibase, tests and so forth. From the front-end perspective, it also creates the controllers, views and a couple more things. There's why JHipster relies on the entities being created using its generator. Anyways, you can always check the release notes and see if this feature has been implemented: [Release notes](https://jhipster.github.io/releases/)